# Grails 3.0.9 JodaTime format YML

Tags: grails, grails-orm, yaml, grails-plugin

I want to use a regular time representation in the database.

In Grails 2.x uses

```
grails.gorm.default.mapping = {
    "user-type" type: org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime, class: org.joda.time.DateTime
    "user-type" type: org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDate, class: org.joda.time.LocalDate
}
```

I have a problem like this written in YML format.
please help me

Answer (score 0):

According to [Issue 9930](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9330), the Grails 3.0 .yml doesn't seem to support the *user-type*.  It uses the Config DSL to create this GORM entry.  I have not found a way to use a YML format for this one.

I just use the *application.groovy* for this one and *application.yml* for all other configurations (so far).  Having both files seems to work.

Not a great solution, but I get the feeling that the Grails team really likes the YML approach.  I have learned that it is good to stick with what the team likes :).

Comment: Disadvantage of the closure approach in application.groovy is, that Jackson has a problem with it currently. So accessing the spring-boot /env actuator currently leads to Jackson errors. See https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10279